# Increase and decrease in depth of CNN blocks

Tags: cnn, convolutional-neural-network

Please see the image below as an example. To my understanding, the 1*n*n image is converted to 500*n~ * n~ with the help of 500 kernels applied on the same image. What I am confused about is how in the next step our output gets to be with depth from 500 to 200. Can someone please guide me of the operations involved.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: As the image and text note, they simply apply a convolutional layer of 200 x 1 x 1 with a ReLU activation to end up with a tensor of shape 200 x n x n.

Comment: Of course! what I am confused about, however, is how we can do that. Like I mentioned in the case of 1 depth image being gone through 500 kernels to give 500 depth image, ehat are the operations that squeeze this image to 200 depth?

Comment: This is more of a general question on how convolutions work rather than a model specific question. I would have a look at explanations on convolutional neural networks, such as [this one](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-convolutional-neural-networks-the-eli5-way-3bd2b1164a53). There is a specific animation in there that shows how a convolution works when the input has multiple channels (see also [this answers on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27754542/9435355)).

Comment: Indeed, the stackoverflow page proved of great help. Thanks dear